# How do I set the MinValue of a RadNumericTextBox to the value being edited

Tags: asp.net, .net, grid, telerik, edit

I have a RadnumericTextBox within a GridTemplateColumn inside a RadGrid and I would like to be able to set the MinValue property to the initial value being edited before the user can change it. The idea is that the user can continue to increase the value but can not decrease it once it has been saved.

I have been trying to come up with some solution server side but from what I can tell the grid template column is not part of the grid rendering.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="StudentGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True"
            OnNeedDataSource="StudentGrid_OnNeedDataSource"
            runat="server">
    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn AllowFiltering="False" HeaderStyle-Width="25px" DataField="Sunday"
          HeaderText="Sunday" UniqueName="SundayColumn">
       <EditItemTemplate>
          <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="editTextBox" Type="Number" MinValue="0" MaxValue="9"
                DisplayText='<%# Bind("Sunday") %>' AllowOutOfRangeAutoCorrect="true" runat="server">
             <NumberFormat GroupSeparator="" DecimalDigits="0"></NumberFormat>
          </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
       </EditItemTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
          <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Sunday") %>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

**UPDATE**: It turns out that a grid template is rendered once on the page and re-used for every cell that in that column. It gets re-positioned and materialized on top of whichever cell is being edited. Since it is not bound to any particular cell there is no information about the cell being edited associated  with it prior to the page being rendered. See below for my client side solution.

Comment: Roland, this has nothing to do with [tag:asp-classic]. Please [learn the difference](http://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/AspNet-Tutorial-26.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to intercept the client side OnCellSelecting grid event along with the OnFocus/OnBlur RadNumerictextBox events.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="StudentGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True"
    OnNeedDataSource="StudentGrid_OnNeedDataSource"
    runat="server">
    <ClientSettings>
        <Selecting CellSelectionMode="SingleCell"></Selecting>
        <ClientEvents OnCellSelecting="StudentGrid_OnCellSelecting"/>
    </ClientSettings>
    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn AllowFiltering="False" HeaderStyle-Width="25px" DataField="Sunday"
          HeaderText="Sunday" UniqueName="SundayColumn">
       <EditItemTemplate>
          <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="editTextBox" Type="Number" MinValue="0" MaxValue="9"
                DisplayText='<%# Bind("Sunday") %>' AllowOutOfRangeAutoCorrect="true" runat="server">
             <NumberFormat GroupSeparator="" DecimalDigits="0"></NumberFormat>
             <ClientEvents OnFocus="onEditTextBoxFocus" OnBlur="onEditTextBoxBlur"></ClientEvents>
          </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
       </EditItemTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
          <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Sunday") %>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

And then add these javascript event handlers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onEditTextBoxFocus(sender, eventArgs)
    {
        // sender is the RadNumericTextBox and does not contain any information
        // about the grid row so we have to look at it's parent to get the
        // grid row cells
        var cells = sender.get_parent().get_element().cells;
        // Switch from Telerik to jQuery to locate selected cell and get it's initial value
        var selectedCell = $(cells).filter('.rgSelectedCell');
        var initialValue = selectedCell.attr("InitialValue");
        sender.set_minValue(initialValue);
    }

    function onEditTextBoxBlur(sender, eventArgs)
    {
        // Have to reset this value because it's interfering with
        //validation on next cell being edited
        sender.set_minValue(0);
    }

    function StudentGrid_OnCellSelecting(sender, eventArgs)
    {
        // Get the grid cell being selected
        var columnName = eventArgs.get_column().get_uniqueName();
        var data = eventArgs.get_gridDataItem();
        var cell = data.get_cell(columnName);
        var initialValue = cell.getAttribute("InitialValue");
        // Set inital value if it doesn't already exist
        if (initialValue == null)
        {
            var cellValue = cell.innerText.charAt(0);
            if (cellValue == '') cellValue = 0;
            // Set an InitialValue attribute in the cell about to be edited
            // This will be picked up by the RadNumericTextBox when it gets focus (see above)
            cell.setAttribute("InitialValue", cellValue);
        }
    }
</script>
```

The OnCellSelecting event handler fires (first) on the cell select and captures the initial value of the cell before editing begins and stores it in an InitialValue attribute on the grid cell. This is needed because the same RadNumericTextBox is used to edit every cell that uses the grid template.

Later when the RadNumerictextBox gains focus the initial value is retrieved from the grid cell attribute and applied to the MinValue of the RadNumerictextBox. When the RadNumericTextBox loses focus the MinValue needs to be reset to 0 because it seems to carry over to validation on the next cell that is edited.